# How to disable mipmaps in blender 2.7?

Tags: texturing, 3d-view

I know I can go to User Preferences, System, OpenGL, and disable mipmaps, but it doesn't seem to work, because the texture stays blurry.

Is there another way of doing that?

Comment: restart blender?

Comment: Are you trying to disable mip mapping in  the viewport or in the render?

Comment: Viewport, and already restarted

Comment: It works fine for me.. Could you upload an image/blend which has this issue?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ux9t922rt2adg22/untitled.blend I am using a background image

Comment: If it's a background image, not a texture, then mipmaps is not applied. You will have to scale the image up in photoshop (or similar) and turn on nearest neighbour filtering.

Comment: But it used to works fine in 2.69 @OwMyWrists

Comment: @someonewithpc Disabling mipmapping had no effect on the background image in 2.69 for me. You could try using textured planes instead of background images, see this [post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3339/599).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by disabling the generation of mipmaps with the GPU, in User Preferences