# Background image is blurry

Tags: image, blur

I'm using a low resolution texture (128x64) from an old game as a background image to help me model but it gets blurry (or aliased I guess) which ruins everything.

I heard that one might need to increase the size of texture but if I do that then texture will get messed up and I want to keep all pixels of it in the same place without "JPGing" it.

Is it **absolutely** impossible to get sharp background image? Zooming doesn't help either. My version is 2.79

[image: Screenshot with blurred background image in 3d view]

[image: And the texture itself]

Comment: does this question help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8441/how-to-disable-mipmaps-in-blender-2-7

Comment: the problem it self is that the raster image has a very low resolution. By resolution, it meas that are used less pixels to descriminate an entity like an object. As you zoom in, and as it is a raster image, Blender, or any other software wont be able to increase automatically the number of pixels by area. What you can do is vectorize the image in external software (like Inkscape). Inkscape can try to vectorize automatically or manually. Once you have your raster image vectorized, you can zoom in, and save with an higher quality jpg or png. Remember that the vector image wont give new info.

Comment: @3pointedit Nah, disabling mipmaps did not help. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @MCunha I didn't understand a word why Blender can't just put small textures as background images without messing it up but you did give me a great idea about vectoring the image in order to increase it's size without data loss. I guess I'll have to stick to this solution unless a better one suddenly appears.

Comment: if you take irfranview and do the most easy method of scaling an image, you would keep the pixel blocks.

Answer (score 2):

As workaround, you could get away with `Import Image as Plane` Addon which creates a simple plane that you can use as reference. It actually also creates a texture shader for which you can use interpolation as `closest` in the shader texture node.

[image]

If you still want to be able to position it in front and change the alpha not as convenient as the background image but, you can add transparent and a mix shader. And disable selection mode to let you select object located behind it.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

It might be too late but in Blender - Viewport settings, if you ever limited the Textures size, then you might want to increase it back. This should fix the blurry images.