# Background image blurry

Tags: image

I like using an empty with an image as a refrence, but the images display blurry when zoomed in.

[image: example of blurry]

Ideally, I would like it to look crisp like this:

[image: Not blurry]

Is there something in the user preferences or somewhere else to do this?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90584/background-image-is-blurry?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late but in Blender - Viewport settings, if you ever limited the Textures size, then you might want to increase it back. This should fix the blurry images.