# Minecraft Reference Image is Blurry

Tags: image

I have a minecraft image as a reference image in my blend file, but it automatically blurs it.  I know how to fix this with materials, but not with ref images.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Question: is the reference image a texture? Minecraft textures in blender become blurry because they are only 16x16 pixels. Could you add a reference image?

Comment: I was adding a reference image, using a png image that I had created.  It is low-pixel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background image is blurry](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/90584/background-image-is-blurry) I don't think you can change the interpolation of a reference image, but if you use the add images as plane add-on (shipped with blender) you can then modify the interpolation of the image texture node in the shader editor.