# I cant see the background images

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, materials, interface

I have toggle the front view and other sides but i cant see any of my imports pictures in the background.

[image: image imput]

Comment: i ha e tried a tutorial posted here too, and still not working

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3339/drag-background-images-in-3d-view

Comment: also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14219/why-does-the-background-image-not-show-in-3d-view-of-blender-2-71

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've set the background image to the viewing position Left, but to show the background image you should be in Orthographic mode not Perspective. Press 5 on keypad to set Orthographic

Comment: im pressing numpad 5, it doesnt doing anything...

Comment: ok, just did it manually... XD... thanks for help!... Now it works...

If someone have the same problem Press [view]>[View persp/orth]